# dataframe manipulation python based on conditons

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

```
input_df1:  ID       MSG         
            id-1    'msg1'                     
            id-2    'msg2'                     
            id-3    'msg3'


ref_df2:     ID       MSG
             id-1     'msg1'
             id-2     'xyzz'
             id-4     'msg4'
```

I am trying to generate an output dataframe based on the following conditions:

1. If both *'id' & 'msg'* values in *input_df* match the values in *ref_df*  = **matched**
2. If 'id' value in *input_df* doesn't exists in  *ref_df* = **notfound**
3. If only 'id' value in *input_df* matches with 'id' value in *ref_df* = **not_matched**

```
sample output:  ID       MSG    flag
                id-1    'msg1'  matched 
                id-2    'msg2'  not_matched
                id-3    'msg3'  notfound
```

I can do it using lists but considering the fact that I deal with huge amounts of data, performance is important, hence I am looking for a much faster solution.
Any little help will be highly appreciated
'''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use `map` to map the ids to the reference messages and use `np.select`:

```
ref_msg = df1['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID')['MSG'])

df1['flag'] = np.select((ref_msg.isna(), ref_msg==df1['MSG']),
                        ('not found', 'matched'), 'not_matched')
```

Output (`df1`):

```
     ID     MSG         flag
0  id-1  'msg1'      matched
1  id-2  'msg2'  not_matched
2  id-3  'msg3'    not found
```

Comment: @BEN_YO Happy thanksgiving. My thanksgiving was a month ago :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `indicator=True` parameter of `df.merge`:

```
In [3867]: x = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True).groupby('ID', as_index=False).last()

In [3864]: d = {'both':'matched', 'right_only':'not_matched', 'left_only':'notfound'}

In [3869]: x._merge = x._merge.map(d)

In [3871]: x
Out[3871]: 
     ID     MSG       _merge
0  id-1  'msg1'      matched
1  id-2  'xyzz'  not_matched
2  id-3  'msg3'     notfound
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and the most Pythonic way of doing what you want to do is to use dictionaries, as shown below:

```
list_ID_in = ['id-1', 'id-2', 'id-3']
list_msg_in = ['msg1', 'msg2', 'msg3']

list_ID_ref = ['id-1', 'id-2', 'id-4']
list_msg_ref = ['msg1', 'xyzz', 'msg4']

dict_in = {k:v for (k, v) in zip(list_ID_in, list_msg_in)}
dict_ref = {k:v for (k, v) in zip(list_ID_ref, list_msg_ref)}

list_out = [None] * len(dict_in)
for idx, key in enumerate(dict_in.keys()):
    try:
        ref_value = dict_ref[key]
        if ref_value == dict_in[key]:
            list_out[idx] = 'matched'
        else:
            list_out[idx] = 'not_matched'
    except KeyError:
        list_out[idx] = 'not_found'
```